# How can I add href parameter dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have trouble make href dynamically> I want to put json type variable as parameter. As below, I want to change filename dynamically.

```js
var fname=file_info.data.file_name;
        alert(fname);


        var rowNode = table.row.add( [
            "",
            status,
            res.data.client_name,
            wtax_file_type,
            month,
            res.data.tax_date,
            total_amount,
            "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><a href='/wtax2/download?filename=312.pdf' id='file_download'><i class='icon-file-pdf text-error'></i><span>파일이름.pdf</span></a></button>",
            "<a class='btn-link color-primary'>[이동]</a>"
        ] ).draw().node();
```

currently a tag href parameter is set for filename=312.pdf. But i want to make it dynamically. how can i write code here??

Comment: Well, if you dynamic filename is "fname", then:

<a href='/wtax2/download?filename='+fname+'.pdf' id='file_download'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have variable set, called `fname`.

If this variable is holding your filename you can just attach it to your `add()` function.

```
var fname=file_info.data.file_name;
        alert(fname);


        var rowNode = table.row.add( [
            "",
            status,
            res.data.client_name,
            wtax_file_type,
            month,
            res.data.tax_date,
            total_amount,
            "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><a href='/wtax2/download?filename="+fname+"' id='file_download'><i class='icon-file-pdf text-error'></i><span>"+fname+"</span></a></button>",
            "<a class='btn-link color-primary'>[이동]</a>"
        ] ).draw().node();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already `id` to your anchor, so you easily set it dynamically.

```
var fileLink = document.getElementById('file_download'); // get element by id
fileLink.href = "someurl";
```

OR if your variable `fname` is dynamic then you can set is as follow.

```
var fname=file_info.data.file_name;
        alert(fname);


        var rowNode = table.row.add( [
            "",
            status,
            res.data.client_name,
            wtax_file_type,
            month,
            res.data.tax_date,
            total_amount,
            "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><a href='/wtax2/download?filename="+fname+"'.pdf'  id='file_download'><i class='icon-file-pdf text-error'></i><span>파일이름.pdf</span></a></button>",
            "<a class='btn-link color-primary'>[이동]</a>"
        ] ).draw().node();
```